# Generator exercise in Udacity not considered correct?

Tags: python

I'm doing the Introduction to Python course in Udacity. I'm given this code:

```
lessons = ["Why Python Programming", "Data Types and Operators", "Control Flow", "Functions", "Scripting"]

def my_enumerate(iterable, start=0):
# Implement your generator function here

for i, lesson in my_enumerate(lessons, 1):
     print("Lesson {}: {}".format(i, lesson))
```

I'm supposed to write a generator function that'll make the code output this:

```
Lesson 1: Why Python Programming
Lesson 2: Data Types and Operators
Lesson 3: Control Flow
Lesson 4: Functions
Lesson 5: Scripting
```

This was the answer I came up with:

```
lessons = ["Why Python Programming", "Data Types and Operators", "Control Flow", "Functions", "Scripting"]

def my_enumerate(iterable, start=0):
    # Implement your generator function here
    for start in range(len(lessons)):
        lesson = iterable[start]
        start += 1
        yield start, lesson

for i, lesson in my_enumerate(lessons, 1):
    print("Lesson {}: {}".format(i, lesson))
```

It outputs correctly, but when I click submit answer, the website says that my code raised an error. I feel like I'm doing something wrong here, instead of the website being broken or something. I just started learning about generators, so I think I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two bugs:

- You ignore the given `start` argument, instead always start with `1`. So for example with `my_enumerate(lessons, 42)` your output wouldn't change.
- You assume that the iterable supports the `len()` call. It might not. It might not even be finite.

Fixed version:

```
def my_enumerate(iterable, start=0):
    index = start
    for value in iterable:
        yield index, value
        index += 1
```

(Instead of the extra `index` variable, you could increment `start`, but that would deviate from the word's meaning.)